# Fixed point of a continuous function

Tags: calculus, analysis, continuity

There is $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$. f is continuous. Show that there has to be always an $a \in [0,1]$ so that $f(a)=a$.

This was an exercise on my last exam and i already know to prove it but i would like to know if there is a easier way solution.

Comment: No actually not. Your theorem tells me that f will hit every value in $[0,1]$ but not especially that there has to be a value $a$ which plots to itself.

Comment: You apply the intermediate value theorem to the function $g(x)=f(x)-x$.

Comment: I just do not think of any easier method other than taking $g(x) =f(x)-x$ and applying IVT. How did you do it?

Comment: Exactly this way. But almost no one in my whole class tried to do it this way so i think this way is a little bit unintuitive. Thats why i asked for a more simple version.

Comment: And how did they do then ? To me this the easiest solution as well. This in not unintuitive, because the statement clearly indicates that IVT may be a good tool for it since you are considering a continuous function on a closed interval. In addition, $f(a)=a \implies f(a)-a=0$ then $f(x)-x$ appears quite naturally.